# Pasting extended ACL contents into telnet session to Cisco Router SIM

Tags: cisco, telnet, dynamips

I have a telnet session to a dynamips router sim.  When I try to paste the contents of an actually working ACL retrieved from 'show run' into the access list, only part of gets pasted.  The session is something like:

```
enable
conf t
ip access-list extended Internet
<PASTE of Rules>
```

It stops right in the middle of a line:

```
permit tcp any host 123.123.123.123 gt 1
! should be gt 1023
```

Anyone know what is happening? The source is an extended access list.

Comment: I have no problem pasting the same contents in the a netcat listening  session via the same telnet client.

Comment: Actually, the 'telnet' session is actually to the console port, so maybe there is a buffer limit?

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a buffer limit. If you copy the ACL in smaller sections (paste 5-10 lines, follwed by 5-10 lines, follwed by...) does the same thing happen?